# Parsing coordinates in json to show on a map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I am trying to use google maps api to show path of a user using a polyline. I am getting the coordinates in json format from a rest api i created. The api is working correctly but the map is not showing the path. Here is the json format

```
[{"user":"qwerty","latitude":28.648036,"longitude":77.2326533},{"user":"qwerty","latitude":28.646096,"longitude":77.183385},{"user":"qwerty","latitude":28.640015,"longitude":77.168119},{"user":"qwerty","latitude":28.644299,"longitude":77.162207}]
```

and here is the javascript code i am using for the map

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>

<script>

    var username = "<%= session.getAttribute("Member").toString() %>";

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $.ajax({
               url: "http://127.0.0.1:8082/letstravel/location/"+username,
               dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    for(var i in data){
                        flightPlanCoordinates.push({ lat: data[i].latitude, lng: data[i].longitude });
                    } 
                        }
           });  
      });

    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      });


      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });

      flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
</script>
```

flightPlanCoordinates should be in this format :

```
flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];
```

This does not seem to work. I think I am not handling json correctly. Please help.

Comment: How are you including the API?  How is initMap called?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  It probably doesn't need to call your REST API, although if it works without that asynchronous behavior, that is a clue to the issue..

Comment: This is script to use API <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script> . I did not included it code above because i thought that wasn't necessary to the problem. I am just receiving a map on the page, i am hoping to get a polyline.

Comment: Please address any comments in your question (preferably by changing it to include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  Getting the map but not the polyline indicates to me that the `flightCoordinates` array is being populated after the map is loaded, you need to reinitialize the map once that array is populated.  [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/acpf8x3t/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
<script>


    function initMap() {

    var username = "<%= session.getAttribute("Member").toString() %>";

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $.ajax({
               url: "http://127.0.0.1:8082/letstravel/location/"+username,
               dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    for(var i in data){
                        flightPlanCoordinates.push({ lat: data[i].latitude, lng: data[i].longitude });
                    } 
                        }
           });  
      });


      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      });


      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });

      flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already used plain Javascript to implement it, but now i know what's the problem from your solution.

Comment: If my answer is useful please rate it