# Google Maps marker only show marker in specific field

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm very new in writing programs. So my task is to plot markers in a google map card. For Now this are only 2 markers I've done this in javascript and this is no problem, but in relation for the future of this program i need this in an java program with the task that it plot 2 markers but I have to restrict a rectangular shape in ma card and in this shape it should only be one marker and the other marker is outside the field and should not be visible!!!! And this all should be writing in an java program not javascript. 
Background is that this will be in the near future an Tracker like a flight tracker with saved coordinates of multiple markers in an xml file and this coordinates should refresh automatically like a real live flighttracker. for this next step i also connect the javascript with my java programm via websockets.

But at first I need help to write this java program and how to connect it with the javascript where i show the google map card.

Thank you for your help !!!

Here is the code of my java script with the 2 points and with the new java programm i want only show the marker in australia!!!
The two pints i show in this example are from an XML File , this is ok, but this alle should happen in an java programm and not in javascript.

javascript Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>tracker</title>
    <style>

      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
       <div id="map"></div>


    <script>

        function initMap() {                   
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.556603, 30.244127),            
          zoom: 2           //Zoom-Stufe der Karte beim Laden der Seite
        });



        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;           


          downloadUrl("vesselxml4.xml", function(data) {          
            var xml = data.responseXML;                           
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker'); 
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {       
             var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');               
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');         
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(                       
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');       
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');            // 
              strong.textContent = name                                 
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');               
              text.textContent = address                                
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);


              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({                     
                map: map,
                position: point,
                //icon: {                                                 
                    //path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                    //scale: 3
                //}
                //

                });



              marker.addListener('click', function() {                 
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {                        
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {                          

          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}

      </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDuZVG0Z9Ei7ubm5bkAfPsYUI-Wm8C_c-0&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the xml file:

```
<markers>
<marker id="1"   lng="131.044"  lat="-25.363"   name="JUN XING 1"   />
<marker id="2"   lng="101.786155"  lat="26.200722"   name="NO PLANS"   />
</markers>
```

Comment: please remove the java tag - it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: yes i know but i want such an java programm to do this !! to check if these two markers are in a custom rectangular field . and if the marker are in this field it should be shown in the card

Comment: you mean the map talking about card?

Comment: Yes sorry for that !

Comment: And that xml file should also load into the java programm and not directly into the javascript

Comment: So basically I would go for a JSON file where you store all the LatLng data. You can see how to store this data [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462008/parsing-coordinates-in-json-to-show-on-a-map). You can then import this data with the Java**Script** code and do some actions on it like "only display markers when ...". But store/get the values should be the first point you should focus on!

Comment: The question is too big and too general to answer it in a short way, if you only want to show your two markers from the snippet go for my answer below. Would also be nice if you give me an upvote and an accepted answer for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to set markers in Google Maps API v3:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044},
  map: map,
  title: 'JUN XING 1'
});


var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: 26.200722, lng: 101.786155},
  map: map,
  title: 'NO PLANS'
});
```

Insert this into your function initMap() at the bottom after `map` is assigned.

Comment: Ok yes thank you very much . But the problem is, these 2 marker are only to test this . I have xml files with thlusands of markerdata. So if i do this all in javascript it will get performance problems. So i need a java programm which loads this xml file and plot this markers on the map. At the end it should be such like a flightracker which refresh the marker every minute. This is the case why i need a java programm and for the first step it would be ok if i can only load the xml file with a java program and plot this thousands of markers on the map.

Comment: And in the best case that it only plots these markers which fall in a slecific rectangular area which can be defined as australia ad example . So if in this file is a marker which is in africa ...the java programm see ut and doesn't plot this marker to the map . Such a programm were great. I KNOW that this also works with javascript bit if i refresh these markers every minute in the future .. I think this will doesn't work very well .